# What is the difference between INTERSECT and MINUS

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the difference between `INTERSECT` and `MINUS` in Oracle?

Please explain with simple example.

**Example data:**

```
select a_address from a1
```

Returns:

```
America
California
Japan
```

And

```
select a_address from a2
```

Returns:

```
England
America
WestIndies
```

Comment: Better google it... You will find correct answer there...

Comment: This question does not show enough effort by the OP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following statement combines the results with the `INTERSECT` operator, which returns only those rows returned by both queries:

```
 select a_address from a1
    intersect 
    select a_address from a2

-->America
```

The following statement combines results with the `MINUS` operator, which returns only rows returned by the first query but not by the second:

```
select a_address from a1
MINUS
select a_address from a2

-->California      
   Japan 

when you take this to set theory A={A,C,J} B={E,A,W} so, A(intersect)B == > A

A-B={C,J}
```

corect me if i'm wrong

Comment: but while running above queries am getting different solution **intersect** :`no rows selected` and **Minus**:                `A_ADDRESS     
---------------
America         
California      
Japan  `

Comment: could you post [here](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: I already post in SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c63c/2 but am getting different results in SQL developer.why?what's the wrong

Comment: they behave differently on different platforms, ok `then` why not you use `joins` `select * from table a inner join table b on a.address=b.address` -->America (for INTERSECT) && `select * from table a left join table b on a.address=b.address` (FOR MINUS)

Comment: getting error.see SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c63c/7

Comment: see [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c63c/12)

Comment: `select a1.a_address from a1 left join a2 on a1.a_address=a2.a_address`

`select a1.a_address from a1 inner join a2 on a1.a_address=a2.a_address`

Comment: ya i rectified my error but still same am getting same error's in SQL developer.why?

Comment: your queries executing perfectly in SQL fiddle but not in SQL developer.why?what's the wrong

Comment: you better google error msgs -- n accept the answer if it helped ..:)